# TFS Continous Delivery directly to Azure Production Environment

Tags: tfs, azure

As mentioned in here :

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-tfs/

The TFS code will be deployed to Staging Environment.

I'm wondering if we can do something in the TFS so that we can have option to deploy to Staging and/or Production Environment.

Many thanks !!!

Comment: Direct automatic deployments to production from TFS checkin would be a really bad idea. Just because the code is checked in does not mean it works.

Comment: You mean from an on-premises TFS server instead of tfspreview.com?

Comment: @EdwardThomson I'm using tfspreview

Comment: @JasonCoyne What I actually want is to create Staging and Production branch on TFS, So I can merge my code from Staging to Production.
So in Azure I have Staging and Production environment for use

Answer (score 4):

You can set the Alternate Cloud Service Environment property in the build definition in order to customize "Staging" or "Production" as the default.  The default when this property is not set will be "Staging".

Comment: Yeah, I've just found the same description on WindowsAzure site, but I can't find the "Alternate Cloud Service Environment" property.

Do you have any ideas where is it ?

Comment: In VS: Team Explorer -> Builds -> right click on build -> Edit build definition -> Process

Comment: Then 6. Deployment -> Deployment -> Windows Azure Deployment Environment -> Environment

Answer (score 0):

From TFS perspective there is no distinction between staging or production because TFS will deploy where ever you would configure it to publish.

When you use Windows Azure Cloud Services, you can choose Staging or Production slot while configuring your Azure TFS and this way your TFS project will always deploy to configured slot.

Comment: How to configure it on Azure ? I can't find any setting there. There is only "Swap" option to swap between Staging-Production Environment.

By the way, I'm currently using Azure 3-Month Free Trial & TFS Preview.

Comment: Where is this set? can't seem to find it

Answer (score 0):

As Habibi says, you can swap the Staging and Production.
Step 6 on this page: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-tfs/

From step 6 description:

Applies only to cloud services, not web apps. When you are ready, you can promote the Staging environment to the production environment by choosing the Swap button in the Azure classic portal. The newly deployed Staging environment is promoted to Production, and the previous Production environment, if any, becomes a Staging environment. The Active deployment may be different for the Production and Staging environments, but the deployment history of recent builds is the same regardless of environment.

Comment: From the Help Center: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.